# load Magick::Image from string in C++ Magick: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat ' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/458`

Tags: c++, imagemagick

## ImageMagick version

7.0.8-62

## Operating system, version and so on

Debian GNU/Linux 8.11

## Description

The image is downloaded from this URL, which can be loaded normally in the following way

```
        Magick::Image image(file_name.c_str());
        cout << "magick is " << image.magick() << endl;
        cout << "baseColumns is " << image.baseColumns() << endl;
        cout << "baseRows is " << image.baseRows() << endl;
```

When the file is converted into a string, and the blob is converted into an Image object

```
std::string get_file_contents(const char *filename) {
    std::FILE *fp = std::fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (fp) {
        std::string contents;
        std::fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        contents.resize(std::ftell(fp));
        std::rewind(fp);
        std::fread(&contents[0], 1, contents.size(), fp);
        std::fclose(fp);
        return(contents);
    }
    throw(errno);
}

std::string content = get_file_contents(file_name.c_str());
const size_t len = content.size();
Magick::Blob blob(static_cast<const void *>(content.c_str()), len);
Magick::Image image(blob);
```

an error message will appear: Magick: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat ' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/458`

I guessed it was a problem with my program, so I tried to change the pictures, and it turned out that most of the pictures can work normally, but the pictures with problems that can be opened normally on the browser cannot work normally

Is there anything special about this picture? How should I load Image from string

Thx~

Comment: image url https://images.xinglinpukang.com/upload/doctor/auth/201906/20190613083117525_s.jpg

Comment: What is get_file_contents?

Comment: File->String  already supplemented

Comment: If your file contains a NULL character in the middle, std::string will store only till that character.

Comment: The problem is solved. The picture is compressed in gz format, so it will be wrong to read the string directly into the analysis, thank you for your reply